# Is it safe to switch to the brew ruby system-wide?

Tags: homebrew, ruby

Is it safe to switch to the homebrew ruby version system-wide? Won't it break anything?

The brew version is 3.0.3; the system version is 2.6.8p205.

E.g., by adding the following lines to `.zshrc`:

```
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/lib/pkgconfig"
```

Answer (score 1):

This only affects processes launched from your environment and not the system at-large.

`homebrew` is designed to install on a one-person computer with a user with admin rights. However, when installed, '/usr/local/bin' (on Intel machines) or '/opt/homebrew' on M1 Silicon ones) house the installed software. Since the permissions of these directories and contents, are world-readable/executable, a process can choose either the "local" version or the standard one via an absolute link to the executable or through a PATH search.

`homebrew` will also install `Xcode Command Line Tools` if it isn't already installed.

A more complete overview can be found [here](https://mac.install.guide/homebrew/3.html).

Comment: What about XCode?

Comment: Are there any built-in CLI utils that rely on ruby that I should be aware of?

Comment: @Yurij Run `file {/usr,}/{s,}bin/* | grep ruby` to find out :-) And actually, even if there are some, they probably have `#!/usr/bin/ruby` in the first line so they would pick the "right" version.